# trying to create a json from Response but im getting json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, google-api, python-requests

I've made this python script which fetches access tokens by exchanging refresh token from googleapis
when im triying to createa json() from response to collect access_token im getting JSONDecodeError

heres my code:

```
import json
from os import access
import requests
import pandas as pd

tokens_csv = pd.read_csv('./credentials/tokens.csv')
client_ids = []
client_secrets = []
refresh_tokens = tokens_csv['refresh_tokens']
for i in range(2):
    f = open('./credentials/{}.json'.format(i+70))
    data = json.load(f)
    client_id = str(data['web']['client_id'])
    client_ids.append(client_id)
    client_secret = data['web']['client_secret']
    client_secrets.append(client_secret)

# def get_access_token(client_id,client_secret):
def get_access_token():
    access_tokens = []
    url = "https://googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/token"
    for i in range(len(client_ids)):
        qparams = {
            "grant_type":"refresh_token",
            "client_id": client_ids[i],
            "client_secret": client_secrets[i],
            "refresh_token": refresh_tokens[i]
        }
        response = requests.request("POST", url, params=qparams)
        obj = response.json()
        access_token = obj["access_token"]
        access_tokens.append(access_token)
    return access_tokens
get_access_token()
```

heres the error:

```
  File "C:\Users\Mohan Krishna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Just check the `response.status_code` to see the request status before converting the response body from JSON

Comment: thanks it worked, i have given wrong URL, so response.status_code returned 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be two reasons.

1. Which  @Abdul Niyas PM listed.
2. You might need to convert your qparams to JSON using json.dumps()